# Custom Birth Date field not showing in my account edit details page

Tags: php, woocommerce, user-data

I would like to add a birth date field to both checkout and my account edit details page. I followed the suggested code over at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428150/add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-and-to-my-account-user-details-on-registration) and managed to get the custom field on checkout and admin edit user but the birthdate field is just not appearing on my account edit details. What could be wrong?

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post">

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php _e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <!-- (BEGIN) ADDED: Birth day field -->
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_birth_date"><?php _e( 'Birth date', 'theme_domain_slug' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_birth_date" id="account_birth_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'account_birth_date', true )); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <!-- (END) Birth day field -->

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php _e( 'Password Change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

        <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_current"><?php _e( 'Current Password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
```

I would like the birth date field to appear after the email field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I were in your situation, I would handle it a way different. Here are some first steps to reach our goal:

- Create a folder named `woocommerce` in your child theme (I hope you're using a child theme see here https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-create-wordpress-child-theme)
- Create another folder inside the new `woocommerce` folder named `myaccount`
- Now go to your `plugins folder -> woocommerce -> templates -> myaccount` and copy the `form-edit-account.php` into your created `myaccount` folder in your child theme

Now you've overwritten the standard WooCommerce myaccount page template. This is a safe way because when you change something in the original file, your changes will be lost after the next WooCommerce plugin update.

Now you can open the copied file. You'll see there the whole content of the myaccount edit page.

So all in one the content would looks like this:

```
<?php
/**
 * Edit account form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-edit-account.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.5.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_account_form' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-EditAccountForm edit-account" action="" method="post" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' ); ?> >

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_start' ); ?>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--first form-row form-row-first">
        <label for="account_first_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_first_name" id="account_first_name" autocomplete="given-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->first_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--last form-row form-row-last">
        <label for="account_last_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_last_name" id="account_last_name" autocomplete="family-name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->last_name ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_display_name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Display name', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_display_name" id="account_display_name" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->display_name ); ?>" /> <span><em><?php esc_html_e( 'This will be how your name will be displayed in the account section and in reviews', 'woocommerce' ); ?></em></span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--email input-text" name="account_email" id="account_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <p class="woocommerce-FormRow woocommerce-FormRow--wide form-row form-row-wide">
        <label for="account_birth_date"><?php _e( 'Birth date', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="account_birth_date" id="account_birth_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'account_birth_date', true )); ?>" />
    </p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php esc_html_e( 'Password change', 'woocommerce' ); ?></legend>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_current"><?php esc_html_e( 'Current password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_current" id="password_current" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_1"><?php esc_html_e( 'New password (leave blank to leave unchanged)', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_1" id="password_1" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="password_2"><?php esc_html_e( 'Confirm new password', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--password input-text" name="password_2" id="password_2" autocomplete="off" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form' ); ?>

    <p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'save_account_details', 'save-account-details-nonce' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button button" name="save_account_details" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Save changes', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_account_details" />
    </p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_end' ); ?>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_edit_account_form' ); ?>
```

Now this part is done and you can upload the file again. But you need another part because when the user press the save button, the changes are not saved without this function:

```
/**
 * Save user account settings
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'save_user_account_settings', 12, 1 );
function save_user_account_settings( $user_id ) {

    //Save the account birth date when the user submits the account settings form
    if ( isset( $_POST['account_birth_date'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_birth_date', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['account_birth_date'] ) );
    }
}
```

This part goes into your child-theme `functions.php` file. Now all should work like it should. Please tell me if it works and check your debug log for errors. Because when there are errors, your website will get slower and slower (just to remember).

Comment: I was already using a child theme when making the changes earlier. Anyway, I've updated the codes with yours and everything is working the way I wanted now. Thank you.

Comment: @Juco Thats cool. Can you please accept my answer and give it a thumbs up? I've spent a lot of work into this :) thanks.